# Redirecting Request with base-path from API Gateway to microservice

Tags: java, spring, aws-api-gateway, spring-webflux, spring-cloud

I have an Order microservice on url `localhost:8080/service-order/` with an endpoint:

```
  @RequestMapping(path = "/v1/order")
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class OrderController {
    
    
        @GetMapping("/{orderId}")
        public ResponseEntity<OrderDto> getByOrderId(@PathVariable UUID orderId) {
    }
```

I also have an API gateway  (service with spring react)

```
    server:
      port: 8081
    
    spring:
      webflux:
        base-path: /api-gateway
```

I need the request `/v1/order-card/{id}` to my API gateway to be redirected to the /{orderId} endpoint of the Order microservice.

I have  RouteLocator bean. This:

```
    @Bean
    RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder) {
        return routeBuilder.routes()
                .route("route_id",
                        route -> route
                                .path("/v1/order-card/**")
                                .filters(f -> f
                                        .rewritePath("/v1/order-card/(?<RID>.*)",
                                                "/service-order/v1/order/${RID}"))
                                .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
                .build();
    }
```

I am making a request

```
localhost:8081/api-gateway/v1/order-card/93c0ea08-617e-11ed-b819-00155d0f6513
```

But it only works when I remove `base-path: /api-gateway`  from my yml

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: /api-gateway
```

How can I make it work with path /api-gateway?

Comment: Look at the strip prefix or setpath filters in the documentation

Comment: I tried but I didn't succeed(((

Comment: What does "didn't succeed" mean? Errors? Http status code?